# laravel: Checking for existing records in my database

Tags: laravel, validation

So i have a hotel booking system where that when the user clicks checkout, it should check if a record exists. The record is checked by; if it has the same check in day on that particular hotel. Currently i can select dates and the hotel and go straight to check out without any validation. I have two functions in (PostsController.php) which i need to compress into one as i found it would be much easier to complete, however im not sure really how to structure this.

PostsController.php:

```
    public function getAvailability (Request $request) {
             $user_id = $request->input('user_id');
             $checkIn = $request->input('checkIn');
             $checkOut = $request->input('checkOut');

             $post = Order::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)
                ->where ('checkIn', '=', $checkIn)
                ->where ('checkOut', '=', $checkOut)
                ->get();

            if(count($post) > 0) {
             return redirect()->route('posts.shopping-cart')->with('There is a clash');
             } else {
                    return redirect()->route('posts.checkout')->with('There is no clash');
                }
}
public function getCheckout(Request $request)
{
    if (!Session::has('cart')) {
        return view('shop.shopping-cart');
    }
    $oldCart = Session::get('cart');
    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
    $total = $cart->totalPrice;
    $checkIn = $request->input('checkIn');
    $checkOut = $request->input('checkOut');
    return view('posts.checkout', ['total' => $total, 'checkIn' => $checkIn, 'checkOut' => 
    $checkOut]);
}
```

Here i want getAvailability to be used in getCheckout, I.E. i want getCheckout to be my main function. Also am i doing my function right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion here is to move business logic to your related model. For example you can extract this code:

```
$user_id = $request->input('user_id');
$checkIn = $request->input('checkIn');
$checkOut = $request->input('checkOut');

$post = Order::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)
        ->where ('checkIn', '=', $checkIn)
        ->where ('checkOut', '=', $checkOut)
        ->get();
```

into a function in your `Order` model which will be `checkAvailability` (or something similar) and then you will be able to use this function in your `getAvailability` and `getCheckout` in the PostsController.

Comment: hey dude i got this working, however i cant get the message to appear saying there is a clash you cannot book these dates :/